# Declare AD ID premission (App for Children)

Tags: android, declare

1. If I direct my applications for children and I have SDK 28 and use AdMob, do I have to change anything? Will a string of zeros automatically appear as AD ID?
2. If I update this application for children to SDK 32, how do I remove AD ID?

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Documentation:

1. If you direct your application to children, you should not ask for the Advertising Id, because you will be violating a Google Play Developer Policy: [Apps should not transmit the following from children or users of unknown age](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11043825?hl=en). A string of zeroes will appear if a user opt-out of personalized ads in Android Settings.
2. If you updated your target SDK version to SDK 32, it shouldn't change anything. However when you update your target SDK version to Android 13, then you must insert the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission the your app's manifest.

You can find more info regarding Advertising Id [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en).